# Smoothing a Plotted Function in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I recently had to change the functions that I plot in one of my papers and the changed function has a number of rough sections. I have played about with "samples" and "smooth" to no avail. Even the dashed line has a hilariously bad section where the dash looks like an S.

Minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8, yscale=6]
     
\draw[->] (0,0)--(1.4, 0);
\draw[->](0, 0)--(0, 1.4);

\draw[samples=201, domain=0:1.4,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{0.9*(1+\x^(0.4))+(0.1)*(1+\x^(0.4))^(-9)-\x});

\draw[samples=300, domain=0:1.4,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(1+\x^(0.4))^(1/(0.9-1))});

\draw[samples=100, dashed, domain=0:1.4,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{0.7*(1+\x^(0.4))+(1-0.7)*(1+\x^(0.4))^(0.7/(0.7-1))-\x});

\draw[samples=500, dashed, domain=0:1.4,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{(1+\x^(0.4))^(1/(0.7-1))});

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks for any tips!

Comment: Welcome. PGFMath isn't precise enough for these calculations, it's not made for it. See the manual [on plots](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.1) for alternatives (namely the `datavisualization` library or the more advanced `pgfplots` package) or for a way to let [GnuPlot](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.6) evaluate the values instead of TeX. If you want to produce serious diagrams of functions and other plots, the PGFPlots package is recommended – if not required. You will find many examples and help on this site under its own tag [tag:pgfplots].

Comment: As a quick solution, load the `fpu` library and add `every plot/.append style={/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` to the options of your TikZ diagram.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Many thanks for the information.  That's good to know about Tikz' limitation. It worked fine for the old function, which was basically the same but "more" concave (-x^2 at the end rather than -x). Your tip to use fpu and the associated code worked very well once I combined that with boosting the samples. Much appreciated.